# Spring RestTemplate + Basic Authentication + Post with request Body: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: spring, http-post, basic-authentication, resttemplate

I am looking for a working approach for Rest Client using Spring (5.x) RestTemplate with Basic Authentication + passing Request Body as HTTP Post.

NOTE: the service works fine If I hit request using postman/ other rest client, instead of a java client/ test class.

I am getting 500 Internal Server Error

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:730)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:704)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:459)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.utils.Util.updateFlag(Util.java:125)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.utils.UtilsImplTest.testUpdateFlag(UtilsImplTest.java:122)
```

My Test class:

```
@Test
public void testUpdateFlag() {
    Request request = new Request();
    request.setUserId("aa");
    request.setFlag("Y");
    request.setValue("D");
    Response response = null;
    try {
        response = util.updateFlag(request);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    assertNotNull(response);
}
```

My Implementation util class: where I am setting Basic Authorization in header.

```
@Autowired private RestTemplate restTemplate;

private HttpHeaders getHeaders(){
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + <base64_encrypted_password>);//500
//  headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON); //401
    return headers;
}

public Response updateFlag(Request request) throws JsonProcessingException, URISyntaxException {
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    HttpEntity<Request> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(request, getHeaders());
    Response response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, requestEntity, Response.class);
    return response;
}
```

If I comment out the basic authorization line in getHeaders() method, then it throws 401 Unauthorized, which is fairly logical.

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:730)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:704)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:459)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.utils.Util.updateFlag(Util.java:125)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.utils.UtilsImplTest.testUpdateFlag(UtilsImplTest.java:122)
```

I have tried almost every option suggested over stackoverflow in similar content, unable to identify the exact root cause why setting authorization in header doesn't validate & throws 500 Internal Server Error.

I have spent quite a handful time investigating, with no luck. Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Did you looked around CORS configuration ?

Comment: Hey Zorglube, Thanks,

Comment: Hey Zorglube, Thanks. While testing using junit, not sure if CORS is applicable. this util is an internal class & not a controller class, also I am not calling the service from jquery ajax, but I still tried @CrossOrigin & it didn't help!